# Nude photography, any advice?

Tags: portrait, nude-photography

**Currently I'm very interested in nude photography**. I did [a little session in the past](http://andresrey.com.ar/galeria/mara/) and I'm going to start a new one in less than a month.

**Do you have any advice?** I'm interested in photographic topics, like **how to get rid of clothing marks** or **How do you avoid pornographic shots and concentrate in erotic/suggestive shots**.

Bonus points for anyone mentioning his/her favorite nude photographer.

Comment: Can you make this into a more specific question? (Perhaps more than one separate question?)

Comment: @mattdm Maybe another solution could be turning this into a CW?

Comment: @Andres: I do agree, this question would probably be better suited by breaking it up. For one, the favorite nude photographer should be its own CW, assuming it is not already covered by other "favorite photographer" wikis. You could probably break this question up into "how to compose the shot" and "how to work with the model" questions.

Comment: Those are a lot of complex questions. Are you willing to pay for the answers? If so, check out http://www.moneyshotsbook.com/MONEY_SHOTS.html - It is incredibly detailed and covers everything on the topic. *No affiliation with the product but the author was a guest writer for a publication of mine.*

Comment: I recommend against nude photography. At least wear a lens vest! If you're built like most photographers, your models would probably prefer that you left your clothes on anyway. :-)

Comment: I edited the question to make it more specific.

Comment: One person's "nude art photo" is another person's porn. So you'll never get rid of the "pornography" aspect, as some people consider any little bit of skin to be obscene, let alone an entire naked body.

Comment: How do you avoid boners?

Comment: @Andrei You can't.

Comment: @Andrei sex change operation?

Comment: @jwenting: Yeah, good idea. Not..

Comment: @AndreiRinea but would solve the problem, I never claimed it to be a good idea but this entire discussion is so firmly tongue in cheek it's fitting :)

Answer (score 6):

An important advice I learned from Zack Arias watching his OneLight workshop - not particularly for nude but in general - is to never touch your model. Always make her/him do the required adjustment, be it posing or fixing hair, etc.

In a recent creativeLIVE workshop [Bambi Cantrell](http://www.creativelive.com/courses/posing-and-lighting-bambi-cantrell) demonstrated the mastery of controlling your model with gestures, never touching physically. if you are serious enough about portraiture or boudoir you are highly recommended to watch this workshop.

EDIT: Found [this page](http://www.pixiq.com/article/nude-glamour-photography-posing-tips) (NSFW!) on the subject, and a few more are linked to from there, dealing with different aspects of this art.

Comment: On the other hand... I touch my subjects all the time. I'd even call it a fundamental aspect of how I build rapport with them and I'd never want to do it differently. One of my mentors was a big fan of 'posing' his subjects and you can find guys like Clay Blackmore advising that photographers physically pose and adjust subjects at will on all of his instructional DVDs. *At best* the notion of 'never touch your model' is one approach, but it's definitely not the **only** approach.

Comment: @Jay It's a very sensitive topic. Once model I was going to work with made it very clear before starting the shoot: she didn't wanted anyone to touch her, no matter what or she would decline the shooting proposal.

Comment: I'd say that the same rules for touching anyone go doubly so for models and 10x for nude models. Touch them only if *they* have a strong rapport/friendship with *you*. Clients are not (typically) friends.

Answer (score 5):

The question in its current form is kind of broad—so broad that the answer could be a book. Keeping that in mind, I can give you few book recommendations of books I've flipped through.

### Books

- [Nude Photography: The Art and the Craft](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0756631769). Baetens, Pascal.

  - Covers history, style, techniques (both camera and human), post-production and a lot of examples.
- [The Naked and the Lens: A Guide to Nude Photography](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0240811593). Benjamin, Louis.

  - Covers kind of the same topics as Baetens' book. Maybe a bit more technical (well, it has few diagrams) and gives more words on finding models, compensating, copyright and regulations.

Generally Benjamin's book has more text that describes the photographs, while Baetens' book has more photographs to describe the text. Still, both have good textual info and a lot of example photographs.

- [Lighting the Nude: Top Photographers Reveal Their Secrets](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0817400060). Hicks, Roger; Schultz, Frances & Luck, Steve.

  - ([Link to older, OOP, edition](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/294037810X) that has "Click to look inside" feature.)
  - Focused on the lighting. It is kind of a practical "recipe book": lighting diagrams and technical info of the setting are followed by an example photograph—not much else.

Comment: I think these are less adult-industry-ish than the Money Shots @Itai suggested (but who am I to judge a book by its cover). While I was at it, I made this answer as CW, so others could add own suggestions / in-depth notes on the books.

Answer (score 1):

1. Experiment. This doesn't mean just trying new things, but to branch out repeatedly from the same point of departure.
2. To avoid pornographic shots, practice abstract drawing exercises. Learn about art and composition, not just the mechanics of photography.

Comment: If you can't draw, go download a copy of [DAZ Studio](http://daz3d.com/) and play with the free content it comes with. More is available online. Don't sink money into paid content if all you want to learn is composition. Better to just play with the software's render camera: set the aspect ratio to the same as your camera's, then play around with focal length, most objects around, etc. You can compose a shot with a 24mm focal length, change to 50mm and recompose to enclose the same frame, and it'll look different!